# Override package localization in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

It should be "trivial", but after some chating on #laravel irc channel, I found it may be impossible for now. But I'll ask it here before doing it the ugly-go-horse way just to have the project done. If it's indeed impossible by current means, I'll fill a request on github (after handing over the project to my client).

I'm using `Zizaco\Confide` to handle authentication in my service. It uses Laravel `Lang` everywhere to get strings in one of the 8 bundled languages of the package. But I need to override some of those strings, and I don't want to modify the package files (which would defeat the whole purpose of Composer). How can I do this?

For example, I needed to modify `confide::confide.alerts.wrong_credentials` for `pt_BR` language. What I tried so far:

- `/app/lang/pt_BR/confide.php` file, with contents `return array('alerts' => array('wrong_credentials' => '...'))`. It works for `Lang::get('confide.alerts.wrong_credentials')` but not for the namespaced `Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.wrong_credentials')`
- `/app/lang/pt_BR/packages/zizaco/confide/confide.php` with `return array('alerts' => ......)`
- `/app/lang/pt_BR/packages/zizaco/confide/confide/alerts.php` with `return array('wrong_credentials' => ...)`
- `/app/lang/packages/zizaco/confide/pt_BR/confide.php` with `array('alerts' => array('wrong_credentials' => '...'))` - `/app/lang/packages/zizaco/confide/pt_BR/confide/alerts.php` with `return array('wrong_credentials' => ...)`

Any clue on what am I missing? Or does Laravel4 really lacks this feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

actually it fixed in Laravel 4.1 core

you can now overwrite it by doing

```
app/lang/packages/(locale)/confide/confide.php
```

check this

[laravel 4 language issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2467#issuecomment-26211312)

[correct path for overriding package languages](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2467#issuecomment-26211312)

Answer (score 4):

So, as for today, Laravel really does lack this feature.
I've asked for it creating a [issue on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2467#issuecomment-26211312).

Meanwhile, this functionality could be achieved **seamlessly** using crynobone's Orchestra Platform 2 Translation Component, which can be found [here](http://orchestraplatform.com/docs/2.0/components/translation/)

All you need to do is `require` it in `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "orchestra/translation": "2.0.*"
    }
}
```

and replace the original translation package (`'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider'`) in `/config/app.php`

```
'providers' => array(
    //'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    // ...
    'Orchestra\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
),
```

That's it! Now, having `app/lang/en/packages/confide/confide.php` will do it!
(please note that the path should be /packages/**packagename**/, not /packages/vendor/packagename/

It really saved me from a big headache, hope others find this useful too.

Comment: and make sure that you run composer update before editing the providers list, not after (as I did by mistake) :)